# Use remote serial port as a local one

Tags: ssh, serial-port

I am trying to develop some software for my charge controller but the only device that I can use it with is my raspberry pi (just because I don't want my PC downstairs) anyways it communicates via /dev/ttyUSBX on the remote device.

I was hoping I could create a virtual serial port on my local machine and connect it via SSH preferably otherwise unencrypted is fine too. Also if it could be a daemon also would be nice so that way it would act like a complete passthrough.

I've looked into socat and ser2net but either no data was passed through or socat would close after one command was sent. I've also looked around for tutorials but it usually just shows an example for the client but not the remote. So if you could give an example for the server and client it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The normal thing to do (assuming you are not running an OS like Plan9 which makes exporting devices easy) us to use ssh to log into your Pi and run a program (e.g. cu or minicom) there. 

If socat does what you want apart from exiting after each "command", then just put it in an infinite loop, e.g. `while true ; do socat ... ; done`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that "virtual serial port" is Windows terminology; Linux doesn't have "virtual serial ports".

What Linux has is a file that supports additional `ioctl`s; if you don't need those, you can try redirection with tools like `socat`.

If you do need those, I don't know a solution. However, what you *can* do is forward USB devices transparently over the network using e.g. [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net). Most Linux distros will have usbip included as packages.

So you treat the USB serial port on the remote device as a local USB device, and then access `/dev/ttyUSBX` on the local device.

This will also forward the USB packets representing DTR, RTS etc. operations in both directions.

Comment: My solution was to use usbip and it works beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My careful reading of `man socat` unveiled the following example:

```
socat PTY,link=$HOME/vmodem0,rawer,wait-slave \
    EXEC:"ssh modemserver.us.org socat - /dev/ttyS0,nonblock,rawer"
```

documented as:

```
- generates  a pseudo terminal device (PTY) on the client that can
be reached under the symbolic link $HOME/vmodem0.  An appli‐
cation that expects a serial line or modem can be configured to
use $HOME/vmodem0; its traffic will be directed to a  modem‐
server  via  ssh  where  another  socat  instance  links  it  to
/dev/ttyS0.
```

Thus, the PC runs a `socat` that allocates a `pty` with a link at `$HOME/vmodem0` and then channels that through stdin/stdout of the `ssh` command, which runs `socat` at the remote end for the similar (but opposite) channeling of stdin/stdout to/from (remote) `/dev/ttyS0`. In parenthesis, the man page suggests using `$HOME/dev/vmodem0` as the link name, but I shortened that just for convenience.

You obviously need to adapt the command to use your raspberry IP instead of `modemserver.us.org`, and `/dev/ttyUSBX` instead of `/dev/ttyS0`, but I suppose all else could be verbatim.

Comment: tl;dr no solution involving socat/ptys/etc will pass through serial line ioctls (getting and setting dtr, rts, etc; and most programs just do those ioctls and don't bother to do any error checking and will lock hard or fail later with stupid errors); many people have wasted their time with that (and with the plethora of serial sniffers which work on the same principle); since the OP is short in details, I can assume that socat does not work, as usual ;-)